# How do you prevent paper pulp from sticking to a flat surface as it dries?

Tags: paper, flowers, papier-mache

I poured paper pulp through a sheet of fine stainless steel mesh.

I left the paper pulp out to dry in the sun for a few days.

The paper pulp is stuck to the steel mesh. It is as if the paper pulp is glued onto the steel mesh.

How do you dry flat sheets of paper pulp in the sun while preventing the paper from sticking to the surface?

Would a barbequing accessory such as a non-stick flat black-colored flexible heat-proof mat for BBQ vegetables work better instead of fine stainless steel mesh?

There exist kitchen blenders designed for fruit smoothies. Sometimes people put unwanted junk mail (paper solicitations) and water into the blender. In theory, the contents of the blender can be poured onto a flat surface and dried in the sun ☀.

I am trying to make recycled paper embedded with colorful flower petals.

[image: Photograph of paper pulp in wooden box having a stainless steel mesh bottom]

Comment: Have you read or seen any tutorial about paper making? Your approach of drying the pulp on the mesh is completely wrong. You have to transfer the wet pulp onto a surface where it can dry and you can remove the dried paper. I'll probably post some tutorials later, but right now I don't have the time.

Answer (score 4):

When making your own paper, the frame and deckle ( = the frame with the mesh and a second frame for straight edges) is only used to lift the pulp from the vat ( = container with the paper slurry). After a short time, the fresh pulp is moved from the frame onto a flat surface where it can dry into a sheet of paper. This process is called "couching".

I've seen different materials used to dry the fresh paper:

- Plastic sheets / cut open garbage bags
- Old bed sheets, tablecloths or t-shirts

I've also seen tutorials that don't use a frame and deckle, but instead something like a metal tray or the lid of a metal box with a cloth on top.

Here are some tutorials to get you started:

- paperslurry.com [How to Make Handmade Paper from Recycled Materials](https://www.paperslurry.com/2014/05/19/how-to-make-handmade-paper-from-recycled-materials/) (which also links to a tutorial on how to craft your own frame and deckle)
- The Craftaholic Witch [How to Make Paper](https://www.thecraftaholicwitch.com/how-to-make-paper/) Uses a simple plastic mesh instead of a frame and deckle
- [YouTube video by NevermindPaper](https://youtu.be/5xrWrKIVBgo) including instructions to make your own frame and deckle
- [YouTube video by Vijayta Sharma](https://youtu.be/u-dgZ9HoihU) shows how to make recycles paper without a blender or frame and deckle